# flask app error while cloning from GitHub and running locally

Tags: github, flask

I have cloned the flask app from GitHub and while trying to run it locally I got an error

```
Could not locate a Flask application. 
You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, 
and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in 
the current directory."
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have followed the [Flask tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask#_refactor-the-project-to-support-further-development), check your current shell.

For instance, on Windows, you would need:

- set "FLASK_APP=webapp" in a CMD session
- `$env:FLASK_APP = "webapp"` in a PowerShell session